# Integrate firebase push notification - React Js web App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I'm Trying to integrate firebase push notification in to my react js app.

I'have followed bellow tutorial

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-push-notifications-on-firebase-cloud-me

https://github.com/pavelpashkovsky/react-fcm

everything working fine up to `Token receiving`.
then i tried to send notification using `curl` script as below

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=AAAAAJjqjp4:APA91bFeAaBEuHXFbcDPBgFs4p......END2341BK8HLL0uMum4" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d '{
  "data": {
    "notification": {
        "title": "FCM Message",
        "body": "This is an FCM Message",
        "icon": "/itwonders-web-logo.png",
    }
  },
  "to": "cG9xo6CkVNs:APA91bEd3ypeXN8P-6dbWQWf0.......NOyIytfm"
}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

but i'm getting below response

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6820287658870793009,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "AuthenticationError"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file inside **public** folder
and put this code

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.0/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.0/firebase-messaging.js')


firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
})

const initMessaging = firebase.messaging()
```

there after create **Firebase.js** inside src folder and config your firebase like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase
```

finality put your code in topbar inside **componentDidMount**() like this

```
import firebase from './Firebase';

 componentDidMount() {
   
    // start push notifications
    const messaging = firebase.messaging()
    messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
      return messaging.getToken()
    }).then(token => {
      console.log("Firebase Token Get::", token)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("firebase push notification error::", err)
    })
    // end push notifications

}
```